# Django-cms example. How to run it?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to run django-cms example. But I think I'm doing something wrong.
Can anybody describe by steps, how to run django-cms example?

Comment: What version of Django are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git clone git://github.com/digi604/django-cms-2.0.git
$ cd django-cms-2.0
```

Open `example/settings.py` and edit your database preferences. To get started quickly, i'd suggest sqlite3.

```
 DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3' 
 DATABASE_NAME = 'example.db'
```

There were some issues with `south` migration (maybe that is what you refer to as problems). To avoid these, comment out the `'south'` application from `INSTALLED_APPS` for now.

```
$ touch example.db
$ python manage.py syncdb
...
```

Now enable `'south'` again in your settings.

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
...
```

Now pretend to migrate:

```
$ python manage.py migrate --fake
```

And run:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Go to http://localhost:8000 and [add](http://localhost:8000/en/admin/cms/page/add/) some pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first problem after **Successfully** setting up django-cms-2.0 site is that it wont run because it lacks any pages to show. If you add pages from admin, it starts working just fine.

2nd problem is, that there could be no templates set up in settings.py or the templates dont have necessary tags (if you added your own template files).

But other than that, it all should work just fine, if you set it up like that  : http://www.django-cms.org/en/documentation/2.0/installation/